# How to disable all fonts in Photoshop on Windows?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, font-management, windows

I've been researching how to handle a font collection for use in Photoshop since the built-in tools are, politely phrased, rather limited.

The consensus seems to be that the best way is to use a third party font manager that operates on the OS level by installing/uninstalling fonts from a broader collection as required.

I've now installed *MainType* for Windows and uninstalled all fonts except for the seven system fonts that are protected. When I launch Photoshop, I still get a lot of clutter (30 to 40 fonts) that I don't want. They seem to be [required](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/troubleshoot-fonts-photoshop-cs5.html#main_Required_fonts_in_Photoshop_CS6) for Photoshop to run.

**Is there any way to remove these fonts from view? Especially since half of them are foreign types in Hebrew, Chinese, Arabic and Japanese which I will most likely never ever use.**

[image]

If I'm going to rely on an extensive third party application to manage and select fonts, it would be nice if Photoshop would at least be clean of clutter.

Comment: Why is the "close" reason "off-topic because tech support"? Font management is a vital part of graphic design as much as vectors or resolution are. This question is as valid as asking why a cdr cannot be opened in Illustrator, why is XYZ Photoshop/Illustrator/GREP script doesn't work, or why my Indesign doesn't print a booklet in printer spread...!

Comment: This is clearly tech support @go-meek as are *all* the other examples you posted. If it is necessary to know the operating system, it's tech support. If the question is about fixing or altering an application functionality, its tech support. This has been discussed **at length** on meta.

Comment: @Scott The same thing happens on OSx or Windows to my knowledge. The other examples I mentioned were not close with the "tech support" reason (not close at all actually.) You can't know if the solution requires fixing or altering the system unless you know the answer already; with this logic, all font managements software are tech support related since that's what they do. Hopefully the OP will find his answer on SuperUser and maybe post the link for the answer here.  Or maybe I'll stalk his profile to see if he asks it there so I can also benefit from that answer...  or ask it myself I guess.

Comment: This is **not** the place to argue it @go-meek

Comment: -- shrugs -- My comment contains additional info related to the question.

Comment: If you want to discuss whether or how a policy that has already been astablished on Meta applies to a certain question and this is straightforward, you can do so in the comment. If you want to debate the policy itself, Meta is the place to do it.